# How to get all Created Class Names in Parse using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Can anyone please tell me a way to `Query` the list of classes created in the Parse Core. I am using Swift 2.0 and XCode 7.

Basically, I have 4 different classes (example : Class1, Class2, ClassName3, ClassName4) holding the different data. I want to get only the class Names and display it in my app using `PFQueryTableViewController`.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "ClassName1")
        query.orderByAscending("songName")
        return query
    }
```

Above code queries the data from ClassName1, however, I want to display the class names not the data within a particular class.

Thanks

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't available via the iOS SDK.

You can get it via the REST interface if you use the master key to fetch the app schema: [https://api.parse.com/1/schemas](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#schemas-fetch-the-schema)

It may be easier for you to just add a `Classes` class with rows for each of the classes, which you manage manually and can simply query with `PFQuery`...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does this mean that I can not fetch data from multiple classes on a single `PFQueryTableViewController` ? I am creating an audio app and want to fetch the Artists and then if user clicks on one artist then want to pull up the data. Any other suggestions, Please ? I am new to IOS development

Comment: No, you can't fetch multiple classes. Usually you would push another view controller to show the details for the selected artist...